# Adding an namespace effect to an Image programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, effect

I am trying to add a custom greyscale effect to an image.
the effect via nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GrayscaleEffect/

I am trying to add the effect to an image like so:

```
Image.Effect = new GrayscaleEffect { };
```

And I am getting an error that tells me that GrayscaleEffect is a namespace, and I can't use it like so.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GrayscaleEffect` class is defined in the `GrayscaleEffect` namespace:

```
Image.Effect = new GrayscaleEffect.GrayscaleEffect
{
    DesaturationFactor = 1.0
};
```

As Ian reminds me, you can also add `using GrayscaleEffect;` at the top of your C# file, to avoid having th explicitly mention the namespace every time you reference the class:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using GrayscaleEffect;

//...snip...

Image.Effect = new GrayscaleEffect
{
    DesaturationFactor = 1.0
};
```

If you type `GrayscaleEffect.`, with a dot or period after the namespace name, intellisense will present you with a list of the types defined in that namespace:

[image]

This is generally true, and very useful.

Comment: Maybe note that you can also do `using GrayscaleEffect;` to avoid having to specify the namespace.

Comment: Works prefectly, Thank you!